Eigenvalues of Q operator in Brassard's Amplitude Amplification
Regarding Brassard's et al. Quantum Amplitude Amplification and Estimation (arXiv) in which they define
$$
Q = -AS_0A^{-1}S_x
$$
And say

Consider the orthogonal complement $H^{\perp}_{\psi}$ of $H_\psi$ in $H$. Since the operator $AS_0A^{-1}$ acts as the identity on $H^{\perp}_{\psi}$, operator $Q$ acts as $-S_x$ on $H^{\perp}_{\psi}$. Thus $Q^2$ acts as the identity on $H^{\perp}_{\psi}$ and every eigenvector of $Q$ in $H^{\perp}_{\psi}$ has eigenvalue +1 or -1. It follows that to understand the action of $Q$ on arbitrary initial vector $|\Upsilon \rangle$ in $H$, it suffices to consider the action of $Q$ on the projection of $|\Upsilon\rangle$ onto $H_\psi$.

I fail to understand where does the +1 eigenvalue comes from. Of course, if we look at $Q^2 = I$ it means that the eigenvalues are +1 and -1. However, we know that $Q = -I$ so I would think that $Q$ has eigenvalues -1 only.
To clarify why I think that $Q = -I$ in $H_\psi^\perp$ (and also think this where I'm understanding something wrong):
Because $|\psi\rangle$ is defined by $|\psi\rangle = A|0\rangle$ we can be sure that $A^{-1}|\phi\rangle \neq |0\rangle$ for all $|\phi\rangle \in H_\psi^\perp$.
Thus, for $\varphi \in H_\psi^\perp$ it is true that $AS_0A^{-1} = I$ and therefore $Q = -S_x$. However, by it's definition in $H_\psi^\perp$ the operator $S_x$ is the identity. In conclusion, $Q = -I$.
